# Selenium with Ruby: Script not finding options in a drop-down

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, ruby

This is my first post, so if I have missed any info that should be included, please let me know. I am self-learning selenium/ruby automation in my spare time with only a little programming background, so I'm still very new to this.

**Issue**:

I am currently attempting to implement a script that tests new account registration scenarios and have come across an issue where the script does not find the options in a drop-down to select a different country. I've been scouring the internet for the last 4 days trying to find a fix, but everything I've tried either returns an exception or allows the script to run, but doesn't select a new option.

**Some Notes**:

- The drop-down contains 251 country options and the one I need requires scrolling to find which could be the issue as I have gotten a few exceptions while attempting a fix which mention the element not being visible.
- The page uses bootstrap which, from what I understand, could be causing issues with the script.

**HTML Code**:

Here is a link of the full div code: http://codepad.org/Vm0EwMLp

Here is a shortened version:

```html
<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
 <select id="couCode" name="couCode" class="form-control border" autocomplete="country-name" x-autocompletetype="country" style="display:none;">
    <option value="AX">ALAND ISLANDS</option>
    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
    <option value="DZ">ALGERIA</option>
    <option value="AS">AMERICAN SAMOA</option>
    <option value="AD">ANDORRA</option>
    <option value="GB">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
    <option value="US" selected="selected">UNITED STATES</option>
    <option value="UM">UNITED STATES MINOR OUT.</option>
    <option value="UY">URUGUAY</option>
    <option value="UZ">UZBEKISTAN</option>
    <option value="VU">VANUATU</option>
    <option value="VA">VATICAN CITY</option>
</select>
 <span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-top" tabindex="0" id="couCode-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="couCode-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 276.922px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-488" aria-labelledby="ui-id-488" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">
    </span>
    <span class="ui-selectmenu-text">UNITED STATES</span>
    </span>
 <span class="form-control-feedback">
    <i class="material-icons priority_high"></i>
    <i class="material-icons done"></i>
 </span>
 <span class="ui-selectmenu-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-top" tabindex="0" id="couCode-button" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="couCode-menu" aria-haspopup="true" style="width: 276.922px;" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-487" aria-labelledby="ui-id-488" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span><span class="ui-selectmenu-text">
        UNITED STATES
    </span>
 </span>
```

**Selenium/Ruby Snippets**

```
# This resulted in Exception 1
open_menu = driver.find_element(:id, "couCode-button").click
select_list = driver.find_element(:id, "couCode")
options = select_list.find_elements(:tag_name, "option")
option = options.find_element(:value, "GB").click

# Also tried this, which resulted in Exception 2
# select_list = driver.find_element(:text, "UNITED KINGDOM").click
```

Also tried:

```
# This resulted in Exception 3
open_menu = driver.find_element(:id, "couCode-button").click
options = driver.find_element(:id, "couCode").find_elements(:tag_name, "option")

options.each { |option| option.click if (option.value == 'GB')}
```

Tried this, as well, which didn't throw any exceptions, but also didn't select anything in the drop-down:

```
cus_country = driver.find_element(:id, 'couCode-button')
cus_country.click
countries = cus_country.find_elements(:class, 'ui-selectmenu-text')
countries.each {|country| country.click if country.text == 'UNITED KINGDOM'}
```

I tried the following to see if the script was actually finding anything. The output just came back as a bunch of commas, no text for each of the tags, but also no exceptions came up when running this.

```
begin
  dropdown = driver.find_element(:id, "couCode-button").click
  select_list = driver.find_element(:id, "couCode")
  options = driver.find_elements(:tag_name, "option")
  options.each { |a|
    puts a.text + ', '
  }
end
```

**Exceptions**:

1

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:58:in `find_element': cannot find element by :text (ArgumentError)
```

2

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.13.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:58:in `find_element': cannot find element by :value (ArgumentError)
```

3

```
tester.rb:48:in `block in <main>': undefined method `value' for #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x000000000384da70> (NoMethodError)
tester.rb:48:in `each'
tester.rb:48:in `<main>'
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have u used explicit wait ?

Answer (score 3):

Add an explicit wait after you click your menu and then once the drop-down element is present refer below steps:

https://selenium.dev/docs/site/en/support_packages/working_with_select_elements/

Please refer to the above document:

You can use the select class in ruby to achieve this:

```
select_element = driver.find_element(id: 'couCode')
select_object = Select(select_element)
```

**To select using text:**

```
select_object.select_by(:text, 'URUGUAY')
```

**Using Value:**

```
select_object.select_by(:value, 'UY')
```

**Using index:**

```
select_object.select_by(:index, 1)
```

**Issue with your code:**

> This also doesn't work, throws exception

```
options.find_element(:value, "GB").click
```

There is no element locator called "value" that is supported by find_elemnet method. So you are getting argument error saying :value is wrong.

Below are the only supported locators

```
   {
      :class             => 'ClassName',
      :class_name        => 'ClassName',
      :css               => 'CssSelector',
      :id                => 'Id',
      :link              => 'LinkText',
      :link_text         => 'LinkText',
      :name              => 'Name',
      :partial_link_text => 'PartialLinkText',
      :tag_name          => 'TagName',
      :xpath             => 'Xpath',
    }
```

> THis throws error :

You could make below code work by changing:

```
options.each { |option| option.click if (option.value == 'GB')}
```

To

```
options.each { |option| option.click if (option.attribute("value")== 'GB')}
```

Because the option is just a web element and does not contain any method called value. So it throws an error if you call option.value.

> This does not work and does throw error also,

```
country.click if country.text == 'UNITED KINGDOM'}
```

Because it's not an element inside the drop-down, but won't throw any error as syntax is correct.

> Prints just comma:

Here,

```
 options.each { |a|
    puts a.text + ', '
  }
```

instead of  `puts a.text + ', '`. Try,  `puts a.attribute("textContent") +','`